# Sum of normally distributed variables is a normally distributed variable?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, stochastic-processes, normality-assumption

Consider two Wiener processes:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X_a &\sim\mathcal N(0,a)  \\
X_{a-b} &\sim\mathcal N(0,a-b)
\end{aligned}
$$
How do I show that:
$$
X_a - X_{a-b} \sim\mathcal N(.,.)
$$
That is, how do I show that $X_a - X_{a-b}$ is Gaussian?

---

I know that $E(X_a - X_{a-b}) = 0$

and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}(X_a - X_{a-b}) &= E(X_a^2) - E(X_{a-b}^2)  \\
&= \text{min}(a,a) -\text{min}(a-b,a-b)  \\
&= a - a - b  \\
&= b
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Note that both $X_a$ and $X_{a-b}$ have the following properties:

- They are normally distributed with mean $0$.
- Their sample paths are continuous.
- Its covariance function is $\rho(s,t) := \text{Cov}(X_s,X_t)=E(X_sX_t)=\text{min}(s,t)$.

Comment: What definition/construction of a Wiener process are you using? From that you should know much more about it than just the marginal distribution at a fixed time.

Comment: @cardinal Fixed.

Comment: Hi, Jase. Hmm. What is the source of this "characterization" that you've listed? (The properties are correct, but it is not a complete definition of a Wiener process.)

Comment: @cardinal It is presented in my lecture slides for "one-dimensional standard scalar BM". I left out the stuff about the filtration satisfying the usual conditions and the process $X$ being adapted to this filtration.

Answer (score 1):

$X_a = X_{a-b} + \int_{a-b}^a dX_s$

$\Rightarrow X_a - X_{a-b} = X_{a-b} + \int_{a-b}^a dX_s - X_{a-b}$

$ = \int_{a-b}^a dX_s$

$ = X_{a - (a-b)} = X_b$.

Since $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ is a Wiener process and $b \in [0,T]$, then $X_b$ is Gaussian by the fact that $X_b \sim N(0,b)$ (from the definition of a Wiener process).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not correct, as written.

Comment: @cardinal Which line is wrong? I stole the first line from the bottom of page 7 here: `http://www.maxmatsuda.com/Papers/Intro/Intro%20to%20Brownian%20Matsuda.pdf`, then the rest seems to follow.